# No route matches :id=>nil

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, controller, routes

Im trying to link_to another page that keeps the id and information of the previous listed reservation. An example is listing rows of my reservation table so that it shows information then include a button to edit the reservation table after clicking. I added a button and when I get routed to the page I get an error.

**Error:**

```
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Reservations#your_reservations
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"reservations", :id=>nil, :reviser_id=>#<Reservation id: 107, user_id: 4, reviser_id: 1, missing required keys: [:id]
```

How do I obtain this id??

**Html.view(your_reservations)** "at the bottom of the code is link_to"

```html
<% @revisers.each do |reviser| %>
   <% reviser.reservations.where("status = ?", true).each do |reservation| %>

   <script>
    
    var total = <%= reviser.reservations.where("status = ?", true).sum(:total) %>;
    $('#sum').html(total);
    
   </script>
   <div class="panel-body" style="">
    <div style="">
    <div class="col-md-12 " style="border:3px solid black;height:108px;max-height:108px;min-width:703px;">

     <!-- first column -->
     <div class="row" style="">


      <div class="col-sm-3 center " style="">
       <div style="margin-left:-45px;">
        <%= reservation.reviser.essay_type %>
       </div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-sm-2 center " >
       <div style=" margin-left:-40px;">
       <% if reservation.document_file_name != nil %>
        <%= link_to "File Download", reservation.document.url(:original, false), class: "btn btn-download"  %>
        <% end %>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(":file").filestyle({buttonName: "btn btn-download", iconName: "fa fa-paper", buttonText: "Choose Word Doc", input: false});
        </script>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 center " >
       <div style="margin-left:35px;">
        Due
       </div>
       
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 center " >
       <div style="margin-left:70px;">
        <%= link_to "Turn In", edit_reviser_reservation_path(reservation), class: "btn btn-download" %>
       </div>
                              <% end %>
                                <% end %>
```

**Reservation Controller**

```rails
 before_action :find_reservation, only: [:edit, :update]
    before_filter :require_permission, only: [:edit, :update]



def edit
  end

  def update
    if @reservation.update(reservation_params)
      redirect_to your_reservations_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end

  end


protect_from_forgery except: [:your_reservations]
def your_reservations
    @revisers = current_user.revisers
    @user = current_user
    @reservations = @reservations

end

def completed_file_upload

end

def find_reservation
    @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:id])
  end
  def require_permission
    @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:id])
    if current_user.id != @reservation.user_id
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Sorry, you're not allowed"
    end

  end
```

**Routes.rb**

```rails
get '/your_reservations' => 'reservations#your_reservations'
get '/your_reservations/completed_file_upload' => 'reservations#completed_file_upload'
```

I want to essentially edit the reservation on another page!! how can I do this? I tried creating an edit for page but I seem to have it wrong.

Comment: do you have a resource :reservations in your route?

Comment: what's the relationship between reviser and reservation?

Comment: The relationship is that a user makes a reservation, the reviser is included as foreignkey. Im on a page that only the reviser views with all the reservations that have been made. When i click on the link i want to be able to link to another view to fill out a form to edit the reservation page. want the reviser to be able to add another amount of info into a nil column of reservation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix:

```
edit_reviser_reservation_path(reservation.reviser, reservation)
```

Comment: this works!! now I have a problem with my form on the next page if you wanna check it out!!! Ill post it.  Thank you very much!!

Comment: awesome. you could post the additional question as a Github gist, or ask another question on SO.

Comment: I figured it out! but i have a different question about styling that i will post!! thanks!!